# Is memcache store from a cron task in heroku different from memcache store in web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3

I think everything is in the topic title:

I have an application on heroku. This application has a rake cron task. In this task, I want to store some values into cache.

I cache using : Rails.cache.write(key, value). I use md5 digest to generate the key.

Now, in my regular controllers, if i call the EXACT same key with Rails.cache.fetch/read(key), i'm just not fetching the data (stored during the rake task).

So, I was wondering: the cache stores are differents?
If so, how can I create a common store?

Regards,

Comment: Is it possible that your cache values are expiring before you retrieve them?

Comment: That's what i was thinking so I wrote them like that: `Rails.cache.write("#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(artist_name.strip.downcase.to_ascii + album_name.strip.downcase.to_ascii)}", consolidation_results, {:expires_in => 86400}) ` which is one day in seconds. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Do you have config.cache_store = :dalli_store set up per http://docs.heroku.com/memcache?

Comment: Absolutely! That's why I don't know why it's not working. Anyway, I found a workaround, thank's for help!

Comment: What was the workaround?

Comment: Architectural workaround. Let's think about it. I'm using a cron to store some values into a cache. Maybe I thought, this is not the good way. Cache is for "normal" client/server conversation. So I stored it into a value key db, like, let's say, Redis. Problem solved. Hope This helps.